# find next-to-last node with xpath

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, docbook

I have a XML document with `chapters` and nested `sections`.
I am trying to find, for any section, the first second-level section ancestor.
That is the next-to-last section in the `ancestor-or-self` axis.
pseudo-code:

```
<chapter><title>mychapter</title>
  <section><title>first</title>
     <section><title>second</title>
       <more/><stuff/>
     </section>
  </section>
</chapter>
```

my selector:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
    select="ancestor-or-self::section[last()-1]" mode="title.markup" />
```

Of course that works until last()-1 isn't defined (the current node is the `first` section).

If the current node is below the `second` section, i want the title `second`. 
Otherwise I want the title `first`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your xpath with this:

```
ancestor-or-self::section[position()=last()-1 or count(ancestor::section)=0][1]
```

Since you can already find the right node in all cases except one, I updated your xpath to **also** find the `first` section (`or count(ancestor::section)=0`), and then select (`[1]`) the first match (in reverse document order, since we are using the `ancestor-or-self` axis).

Comment: That works--thanks. After trying your solution, I thought I might simplify it with this, but alas it seems to always select the current section. `ancestor-or-self::d:section[last()-1 or last()][1]`

Comment: @Tim `ancestor-or-self::section[last()-boolean(ancestor::section)][1]`

Comment: @Tim `ancestor-or-self::section[position()>last()-2][1]` :)

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a shorter and more efficient solution**:

```
(ancestor-or-self::section[position() > last() -2])[last()]
```

This selects the last of the possibly first two topmost ancestors named `section`. If there is only one such ancestor, then it itself is the last.

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  <xsl:text> --> </xsl:text>

  <xsl:value-of select=
  "(ancestor-or-self::section[position() > last() -2])[last()]/title"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following document** (based on the provided, but added more nested `section` elements):

```
<chapter>
    <title>mychapter</title>
    <section>
        <title>first</title>
        <section>
            <title>second</title>
            <more/>
            <stuff/>
        <section>
            <title>third</title>
        </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</chapter>
```

**the correct results are produced**:

```
first --> first
second --> second
third --> second
```